# How to include %CPU usage in a notification?

Tags: notifications

I have the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sleep_period=8m

while true; do
  if ps -eo %C --sort -%cpu | head -2 | awk 'NR==2 { exit !($1>8); }'; then
      notify-send 'CPU alert!' '......'
      xdotool key shift
  fi
  sleep ${sleep_period}
done
```

But I don't know how to get the notification to print the % CPU value instead of `'......'`.

I'm using Lubuntu 13.10, fully updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your logic correctly, how about this:

```
while true; do
  highest_cpu="$(ps -eo %C --sort -%cpu | awk 'NR==2 {print $1}')"
  if [ "$highest_cpu" -gt 8 ]; then
      notify-send 'CPU alert!' "$highest_cpu"
      ...
  fi
  ...
done
```

If you need a non-integer CPU usage threshold, the following Bash-only solution should work:

```
if [[ "$highest_cpu" > 9.3 ]];then
...
```

Comment: `if [ "$highest_cpu" -gt 8 ]; then` requires an integer?

Comment: @vasa1 Yes. See the updated answer for non-integer comparisons.

Comment: @vasa1 You're very welcome. By the way, I updated the answer: `head -2` is unneeded.